Are unregulated charge pumps used in some applications?
As we see in SMPS converters that feedback is necessary to regulate the output. Here charge pumps are both regulated and unregulated converters.
I am curious to understand in which applications unregulated charge-pumps are used.

When you don't need accurate voltage regulation ...

If you need a negative supply rail for an opamp an unregulated charge pump is a very reasonable choice since small changes in the exact rail voltage won't matter.

Normally, at low currents, where the switching loss of a capacitive load is tolerable, and where regulation isn't required.
High power levels are discouraged because the startup current especially can simply outright destroy transistors; the switching speed, current limiting if any is implemented, and switching rate all determine the feasibility of it.  That said, there are applications, particularly for battery management, where charge pumps are used "at scale".
Note, there are indeed charge pump regulators -- they work either by changing the pulse rate, or adding an LDO after the pump.  Either way, the difference is lost as power in the device.  Power loss can be minimized by using a stack of charge pumps, and selecting the minimal tap required for output voltage.
Some board-level uses include: negative supply for op-amps (analog circuitry, front-end, etc.) so that input/output range includes ground or below; supplies for odd-voltage logic devices (high-voltage programming, vintage parts, many LCD and ePaper displays, etc.); high voltage interfaces like RS-232; etc.
Incidentally, charge pumps tend to be poorly suited to analog application, because they tend to be noisy -- the gulp of charge being pumped tends to pervade the circuit, making all sorts of trouble in sensitive applications.  The added filtering to deal with this, can be worse than just using a switched-inductor type converter.  Both have their ups and downs, regarding in-circuit or external EMC, and there can be reasons to choose either.
Chip-level examples abound; part of the limitation of Flash memory write speed is due to the power available from the onboard charge pump that powers high-voltage erasing/writing.  Older examples include the early NMOS era, when reverse bias was still required (e.g. the i8080 that required +12, +5 and -15V, or thereabouts); removing these supplies greatly improved usability.  Thus, the i8086 for example has a "substrate bias" section on the chip, providing such a supply: 
Inside the 8086 processor, tiny charge pumps create a negative voltage | Ken Shirriff's blog | Righto.com

In the paper, "A Hybrid Cockcroft-Walton / Dickson Multiplier for High Voltage Generation", they ended up with greater efficiency than predicted, which they found to be due to the small inductances of the PCB traces. The excerpt follows: "Interestingly, experimental data in Fig. 14 show less sagging as the number of multiplier stages increases, compared to simulated values with ideal capacitors. ...

... We believe this phenomenon is caused by parasitic series inductance in real capacitors. We confirmed through measurement that 2.2nF capacitors used in the voltage multiplier have an equivalent series inductance (ESL) of 2.8nH, thereby presenting a lower impedance than ideal capacitors over the frequency range of 10MHz to 90MHz. Indeed, simulation produces a better match with the experiment when ESL is included in the model."

Note that efficiency and "sagging" are not the same thing: a voltage multiplier (a nominally capacitive to resistive load) can be driven by an inductive source, absorbing the reactance and converting it to a comfortable inductive characteristic for use with a conventional constant-voltage inverter. One downside is, the voltage regulation goes almost completely away, as the circuit is now a series-LC type resonant converter; but this is easily solved by a (frequency-shift or PWM) control loop. It sounds like they basically find the same effect, but between stages, which is neat.

One use for unregulated charge pumps is raising 1.2 or 1.5 V NiMH or  Leclanché cell to ~3 V to power LED's. Here, intrinsic current limiting of a charge-pump can be an advantage.
One of the older uses was as multipliers for high voltages, the Cockcroft-Walton "generator" (the original doubler was developed by Heinrich Greinacher). Won 'em a Nobel Prize!
